# Change TSM Archive Date for a file

Tags: backup, archive, tsm

Is there any way to either insert a file into a TSM archive with a given date, or change the archived date on an existing file in the archive?

Answer (score 0):

If TSM is Tivoli Storage Manager then:
(inserting a file in an archive probably is impossible, but modifying existent file information might be feasible)
 
 - First of all, performing any operation described bellow might corrupt your database, your best bet will be to contact IBM Support they can provide such assistance so you might as well stop reading here and downvote my answer :) 
 - but... Considering all the information about any backup or archive performed are stored in a database there are ways of modifying entries in it. (things even get a lot more easier with tsm 6.1+ because of the full db2 database it is using but most likely you are using an earlier version.)
 
You should only be doing this under IBM supervision.

- 1: Backup your TSM Server DB.
- 2: Halt your TSM Server.
- 3 add this to your opt file:

> NOMIGRRECL
>
> DISABLESCHED YES
>
> EXPINT 0

- 4: Start your TSM Server in the foreground, execute `disable sessions`.

(3 & 4 are to prevent processes/sessions/schedules from starting, undo 3 & 4 when done.)

There are a set of commands integrated in TSM for which IBM does not offer support.
(not all the commands shown bellow will work in any version of TSM, also information is not accurate and should be treated as an example this is not exactly what you need to do!)

- SHOW OBJDIR
  will display all the defined database object names, along with their numeric node identifier. Output looks like

> Defined Database Object Names (Home
>   Address):
>
> ```
> Activity.Log(49), Activity.Summary(50), 
> Administrative.Attributes(37), Administrators(40), etc..
> ```

- -Show NODE number

  Will display details of one of these nodes.
  Example:

  `Show Node 49` your number might be different.

  > ```
  > B-Tree ROOT node: PageAddr=49, Lsn=121563.242.2284,
  > ```
  >
  > ObjName=Activity.Log
  >       LeftSib=-1, RightSib=-1, Continuation=-1
  >       NumRecs=2, Free=994, NextSlot=163, DirOff=0, PartKeyLen=0
  >       Level=2, NumCols=19, KeyCols=2, PartCols=0, NodeAttr=80
  >       MaxCapacity=1004, Capacity=1004, Occupancy=10, LowOccupancy=334
  >         Record 0 (KeyLen=9, DataLen=4):
  >           Key:  ->(,.....)(002D)< -
  >           Subtree=&gt4152978<
  >         Record 1 (KeyLen=2, DataLen=4):
  >           Key:  ->(+Infinite)(+Infinite)< -
  >           Subtree=&gt4152968<
- show node # (insert record number from subtree)

> look for number of records

- create IBM admin account (ibm.service)(ibm_service)

> Log in as ibm account

- As ibm.service;
  You will be able to do this:

> delete record subtree # record #

or

> setrecord 49 234211 3 MM/DD/YYYY DATE

These are all just examples you will need to thoroughly investigate the output of

> show objdir / show node XX

Resources:
http://www.lascon.co.uk/d005006.htm
http://tsmblog.org/kb/
http://tsmblog.org/serendipity/
http://adsm.org/forum/